# Proof for max. distance between two points inside a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, polar-coordinates

I have an algorithm in mind which can solve one of my algorithm's problems.

The algorithm links Blue-Dot to any of the Red-dot such that their mutual-distance is maximum compared to the distance between blue-dot and any other red-dot.  (see the image below for a better understanding).

I am pretty much clear how to do that but I need more mathematical proves. I have done something on my part as well, but any help which makes it more evident mathematically will be highly appreciated. (I know the intuitive part well, but I need mathematical proof)

1. The central-node (black-dot in the centre, knows the cartesian coordinates of all dots and easily gets polar coordinates.
2. The circle is divided into four quadrants. This way Angle $\angle POR$ can easily be found.
3. It is for sure that the red-dot in the same quadrant is out-of-question since it will definitely have a smaller distance compared to other red-dots.
4. Using the law of cosines, length $r$ can be found for the rest of the three quadrants.
5. But, the ideal candidate is the exact opposite quadrant as following the law of cosine $r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos(\angle POR)}$ and in the opposite quadrant $\angle POR$ is very close to 180, hence $\cos(\angle POR) = -1$. This will make $r$ to be maximum. But I need mathematical proof or is this proof enough.

[image]

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You need a mathematical proof of what ?

Comment: If red dots are not fixed (meaning your image is just one of the infinite possible cases) then the third assumption is wrong. I think your approach isn't bullet-proof. I’ll suggest a different way: given $N$ is the number of red dots then $\text{argmax}_{i \in [1,N]} \left|\vec{P}-\vec{R_i}\right|$ return the index of the red dot you’re interested into.

Comment: $Giulio Scattolin: red-dots are uniformaly distributed over the entire 2D plane, I have tried to show only those that are closer to the black dot, since this is one of the consideration that whatever the location of Blue -dot, red dot must always be closer to the center.

Comment: @Giulio Scattolin again, I know I can find that using what you have said, but I have a large number of nodes, and I don't want to use Brute-force algorithm for my design, for this purpose, I have divided the circle in 4-quadrants. Once I have proven that the nodes on the opposite quadrant are most probable to have largest distance with blue-dot, I can then apply your said formula

Comment: @nicomezi, the proof that nodes on the opposite side of the quadrant are highly probable to fall in the category of having largest distance from blue-dot

Comment: @Kashan I understand your point, still I would not employ that. If brute force isn't reasonable for this application then It won't be even for a 1/4 of the points. It looks like you need a stronger algorithm.

Comment: @Kashan I was thinking about a "2D binary tree". Then you can determine the location of the point which is the farthest from the blue one if it existed: finally search from that area.

Comment: @GiulioScattolin, hmm....let me have a look at it (2D binary tree method) later in the day. Thanks for the tip.